# Dynamic Graph Using Websocket Inside Cordova App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, highcharts

I'm trying to create dynamic graph inside a mobile cordova angularjs application.

I've done a bit of research and tried several libraries to plot a graph using a websocket protocol with no success.

I'm starting to think its not possible and would need to program a custom one.

Does angularjs support any live streamed graphs for use?

I would like to use something provided by highcharts a live dynamic spline chart.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/ this is a good example

Comment: Long time ago I made this working using Socket.IO library (sorry, I don't have access to this app and code anymore, so I can not share any snippet). I remember, there was limitation with websockets, that not every telephone operator enables websockets - you can check this for example [here](https://websocketstest.com/).

Comment: I have used a Socket.IO library and it works the thing i'm having troubles finding is a Dynamic Chart

Comment: What do you mean by "Dynamic chart" ? You have posted one, good example. What kind of troubles exactly do you have?

Comment: I want to use it inside a Cordova AngularJS application